# Can you benefit from multiple castings of Evolution Surge?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, eidolon

The [Evolution Surge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/evolution-surge/) series of spells allow an Eidolon to gain additional temporary evolution points which can upgrade them in whatever way the points can be legally spent.

The spell is a transmutation spell, which since the main buff spells bulls strength, bears endurance, and so on are, we know that purely transmutation spells can affect a single target.

So would multiple castings of the spell work? Would the actual choices even matter? So using the points to buy Swim and gills compared to two different elemental resistances, compared to getting two swims?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### This GM would rule that multiple [*evolution surges*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/evolution-surge/) can affect the same eidolon, but this player wouldn't complain about a GM ruling differently

The *Pathfinder* Magic rules on [Combining Magical Effects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/?dti=688257971261882%2F%2Fall-spells%2Fs%2Fsummon-thanadaemon%2F&fref=gc/#TOC-Combining-Magic-Effects) on Stacking on Same Effect with Differing Results says

> The same spell can sometimes produce varying effects if applied to the same recipient more than once. Usually the last spell in the series trumps the others. None of the previous spells are actually removed or dispelled, but their effects become irrelevant while the final spell in the series lasts.

However, the *Pathfinder Core Rulebook*—and, subsequently, the game's system reference document—isn't allowed by the Open Gaming License to reprint the example from the *Player's Handbook* for its antecedent [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) for the rule quoted above, and Paizo deigned not to include its own examples. This absence leaves *Pathfinder* players at a loss as to the scope of the rules as originally presented in the game on which *Pathfinder* is based. To fill that gap, presented below, for comparison and critique, is the *Player's Handbook* Same Effect with Differing Results paragraph:

> The same spell can sometimes produce varying effects if applied to the same recipient more than once. **For example, a series of polymorph spells might turn a creature into a mouse, a lion, and then a snail. In this case, the last spell in the series trumps the others.** None of the previous spells are actually removed or dispelled, but their effects become irrelevant while the final spell in the series lasts. (172)

(Emphasis mine; the *3.5e* SRD [on this topic](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#same-effect-with-differing-results) also omits this example.) 
So, based on that example, this GM sees the rule as a little more fluid, it's goal being to *quash shenanigans*—like a [dnd-3.5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.5e) player saying that his PC should have the lion's ability to bite, claw, and roar while his PC's in snail form—, rather than the rule being a blanket prohibition that can only be overcome by specific exceptions. With that in mind, this GM allows a creature to benefit from the same spell cast on it multiple times *if* each iteration of the spell clearly has a different effect and *if* each iteration of the spell clearly doesn't interfere, overlap, or supplant *other* iterations of the same spell.

Thus to this GM the [*evolution surge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/evolution-surge/) spell appears to be a fine candidate for an exception to the Same Effect with Differing Results rule: the [*evolution surge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/evolution-surge/) spell's description goes so far as to specify *both* that the spell *can't* create the same effect on the same creature more than once *and* that the spell *can't* obviate, render obsolete, or supplant another casting of the spell. This GM would let multiple *evolution surge* spell effects coexist harmoniously and simultaneously, much like he'd allow multiple [*resist energy*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resist-energy) spell effects—if different energy types are picked for each casting—to coexist harmoniously and simultaneously.

(By the way,—thanks to [Forrestfire](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/10963/forrestfire)—I now know that creative director James Jacobs says in this brief Paizo messageboard [post](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=804?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#40182) that multiple-yet-for-different-energy-types *resist energy* spell effects *are* okay, despite the spell not specifying it's an exception to the Same Effect with Differing Results rule. And, further,—thanks to [ShadowKras](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/21153/shadowkras)—I also now know of [this *Advanced Player's Guide* FAQ entry on Spells](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9u3g) that in its own roundabout way pretty much confirms (more succinctly) what I've been droning on about in this answer.)

Nonetheless, as always, the GM must determine the extent of any rule's application, and this player wouldn't flip the table in disgust if told by a GM that because of the Same Effect with Differing Results rule that the spell *evolution surge* could only affect his PC's eidolon once.

Comment: I don't agree with your interpretation, but given a lack of solid evidence for how I read that passage, I don't really have a good reason to not suggest: http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=804?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#40182 citable developer intent is that *resist energy* will stack with itself if you cast it for multiple energy types, so you can probably improve your answer by linking that with your example.

Comment: @Forrestfire I'm honestly humbled by your magnanimity; thank you for the link. And, so you know, if the spell *evolution surge* did *anything* else besides exactly what it says it does—if it granted temporary evolution points, for example—I would've been totally on board with your answer.

Comment: My understanding is not that you can't stack the effects of multiple spells, but that you cant stack the same benefit from multiple spells. So, instead of writing five different spells for Resist Energy, they write one and allow you to choose the different effects. The [FAQ on stacking magical effects](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9r43) will state otherwise, but that's because it had a different context (temporary hit points)

Comment: @ShadowKras I'm not sure of the precise distinction you're making between *effects* and *benefits*, but I think that sounds like you agree with this GM's ruling? That is, like *resist energy*, instead of writing dozens of different *evolution surge* spells, only one gets written?

Comment: Oh, you're right, deleting that comment

Comment: @HeyICanChan That is correct. There are very few spells that allow multiple choices like Resist Energy and Protection from Energy, so we really have few examples to work on. The first spell that comes to mind is [Blessing of Fervor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blessing-of-fervor/).

Comment: Also, [this FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9u3g) about stacking spell effects might be relevant.

Comment: @ShadowKras I was totally unaware of that FAQ ruling. That's actually really significant—essentially saying if it's not a bonus *and* if it doesn't say it doesn't, spells stack… essentially the *positive* version of the Same Effect rule! Would you rather that be part of your own standalone answer than me incorporating it into mine?

Comment: Feel free to incorporate it into your answer, I found it by accident when checking up on Blessing of Fervor.

Answer (score 0):

## No.

A creature cannot benefit from multiple castings of the same spell or spell effect.

A creature cannot gain multiple bonuses to the same attribute by casting the same spell nor than they benefit more than once from the same spell. Any new casting renders the effects of previous castings inert, even if each casting had a different result. This is explained in "Combining Magic Effects" in the Magic chapter of the Core Rulebook.

> **Combining Magic Effects**
>
> ..
>
> **Stacking Effects**: **Spells that provide bonuses or penalties on** attack
>   rolls, damage rolls, saving throws, and **other attributes usually do
>   not stack with themselves.** More generally, two bonuses of the same
>   type don't stack even if they come from different spells (or from
>   effects other than spells; see Bonus Types, above).
>
> ..
>
> *Same Effect with Differing Results*: The same spell can sometimes
>   produce varying effects if applied to the same recipient more than
>   once. **Usually the last spell in the series trumps the others.** None of
>   the previous spells are actually removed or dispelled, but their
>   effects become irrelevant while the final spell in the series lasts.

This rule also applies to combining spells with magic items that use the same spell effect. This [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gg#v5748eaic9qx4) explains so, using the example that *lead blades* does not stack with the *impact* magic weapon ability.

Comment: That's not my downvote; I think there's totally a place here for the GM to say *No multiple* evolution surges *for your eidolon!* But keep in mind that the spell [*lead blades*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lead-blades/) and the weapon special ability [*impact*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/impact/) don't stack because they're actually both [effective size increases](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9t5u).

Comment: Your interperation is incorrect. The first passage of your quote is not relevant for the question at hand, and you misinterpreted the second passage. The first one basically means "two deflection bonusses don't stack, only the higher bonus applies, and don't bother casting haste twice on the same target to get higher dodge bonusses". The second passage is a bit difficult to understand and poorly written imo. For instance if you cast multiple resist energies on a target, aimed at different energy types, it's supposed to stack because it's second effect has not become "irrelevant"

Comment: What I'm saying is, is that a creature CAN benefit from multiple castings from the same spell, but it can't when the bonusses would overlap. In this case the "bonus evolution points" wouldn't stack, but I downvoted because the basis that a create can never benefit from multiple castings of the same spell is flatout wrong.

Comment: HeyICanChan That's' true, but it's also another reason why they don't stack. The FAQ that *lead blades* doesn't stack with *impact* because they use the same spell effect was made 2 years before the FAQ about stacking size increases.

@Snappie The passage explicitly accounts for BOTH cases: multiple castings of the same spell AND castings of different spells with the same bonuses.

Comment: So when the rules say "Usually the last spell in the series trumps the others," when does this — unusually — *not* occur? That is, the answer makes it sound like this *never* happens, yet the rules offer an escape clause.